# How can I keep command line fetch of google sheet from filtering?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I published 1 sheet of a multi-sheet spreadsheet.

I then fetched it with:

```
curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS3iBtVf4i_won5zAN9NGPqhcd6CcTb-4QHxpisSjCmlgV95B6mFmZvtMaC9GPvD7m8kD-6XLkVAhfc/pub?gid=911257845&single=true&output=csv'   >lib/Inventory/Inventory.csv
```

The source is a pivot table.  If I have a filter engaged on the pivot table, the fetch brings in only what passes through the filter.

I can work around this by duplicating the sheet, and never filtering it, but this spread sheet is messy enough with 23 sheets.  Is there a tweak for the url to not filter?  Pointers to the tweak, and to the documentation appreciated.